# Chrome DevTools debugger not stopping at breakpoints

Tags: angular, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Our Angular code base has recently upgraded to Angular 12.
Since the upgrade, the DevTools debugger seems to not work. The breakpoints set aren't being stopped/paused when trying to crawl through the logic.
The `console.log`s seems to show a minified js file `7660.js:1`. I have tried adding `debugger;` line in the code and even that isn't being paused at.

My DevTools setup:

1. Filesystem is currently using the `src` folder
2. The DevTools settings are the default settings
3. I looked through our Git and didn't see any changes in the files that may have changed configurations. The only possible cause is I noticed `webpack-dev-server` was added in our devDependencies

Are there any files/settings I should be looking at changing?